# Are there any EOA multisig wallets?

Tags: wallets, multisignature, eoa

I'm looking to see if there are any ethereum multisig wallets that use schnorr multi-signatures instead of smart contracts? Would be useful for saving gas and potentially using contracts/sites that require interaction by EOA addresses.

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to achieve multisig functionality in Ethereum is with a smart contract.

Comment: You are correct/ However, it can also be achieved by implementing account abstraction at the protocol level. This is being discussed at this time.